# How can use Groovy Postbuild Plugin to write on the project/job main page?

Tags: groovy, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Groovy Postbuild Plugin, and use it to display different info from build logs. But is there any way to write the same info on project page, not the build page? I mean,

```
BUILD PAGE: http://localhost:8080/job/A_JOB/121/ 
PROJECT PAGE: http://localhost:8080/job/A_JOB/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Job::setDescription](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractItem.html#setDescription%28java.lang.String%29) that sets Job description HTML (you do it by hand via `add description` on the job page).